# Java Regex: check if a sentence contains only alphabet and numbers

Tags: java, regex, match

My following program prints weird results that I don't understand, I guess it is due to my lack of great understanding on Java Regex. So I wish to split the `testStr` by period first, then check if each sentence contains alphabet or numbers. But surprisingly, I got the following output, which is opposite to my wish:

```
blah blah1 is not a character!
 blah blah2 is not a character!
 blah blah3 is not a character!
 ??** is not a character!     // only this output is expected
```

my code below:

```
String testStr = "blah blah1. blah blah2. blah blah3. ??**...";
String[] myStrArray = testStr.split("[.]");

System.out.println("length of myStrArray is: " + myStrArray.length);

for (String str : myStrArray) {
    if (!Pattern.matches("\\w+", str)) {
        System.out.println(str + " is not a character!");
        continue;
    }

    System.out.println("got a meaningful sentence " + str.trim());

}
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I expect to get "got a meaningful sentence" for all the sentences except ??**

Comment: `blah blah1 is not a character!` contains not only alphabets but also spaces and `!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program splits string using dot as a separator, so you get:

```
blah blah1 
blah blah2 
blah blah3 
??**...
```

Then you try to *match* each line using regex `\w+`. Please note that call of `match()` is equivalent to call of `find()` but with regex that includes `^` and `$`, i.e. think that your regex is `^\w+$`.

I think that now it is obvious that any one of your strings does not match this pattern because 3 first strings contain space and the last does not contain neither alphabet characters nor digits.

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to: `^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$` it'll allow only characters, numbers and spaces as required. pay attention that part of the "magic" is the use of `^` and `$` which force a full match (from beginning to end).

Further, the reason I've used `a-zA-Z0-9` instead of `\w` is that `\w` includes `_` which doesn't fit the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a character set. Change the regex you are using (`"\\w+"`) to this:

```
"[\\s&&[^\\W_]]"
```

This will allow alphanumerals (`[^\W_]` =>`a-zA-Z0-9`) and whitespaces (`\s`) to be matched, instead of only word characters.